# Why "margin" CSS style doesn't work in FlowPanel (GWT)?

Tags: css, gwt

I am using Gwt.

Say I got

```
.marginRight{
 margin-right: 10px;
}
FlowPanel myFP=new FlowPanel();
Button myButton=new Button("Button");
Button myButton2=new Button("Button2");
myButton.addStyleName("marginRight");
myFP.add(myButton);
myFP.add(myButton2);
```

After ran, there is no gap between `myButton & myButton2`.

**Note:** Button got default gwt-button style. So I am not sure if that the main reason causing the issue. Also, If I add the Label into FlowPanel, then it can recognize the margin nicely. But PushButton doesn't work so we can eliminate that gwt-button style is the main cause.

This is javascript of the above code

```
<div><button class="gwt-Button GHKUF0UDD4" type="button">Button</button><button class="gwt-Button" type="button">Button2</button></div>
```

Do you know why it is? & How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apply two styles to your buttons: gwt-Button, which specifies 0 margin on all sides, and your own style, which sets a margin of 10px to the right.

If you want to use both styles, and your style to prevail, use

```
.marginRight{
    margin-right: 10px !important;
}
```

If you do not want the standard GWT style to apply, use:

```
myButton.setStyleName("marginRight");
```

instead of adding a new style name.

Comment: but will i lose all the current gwt-button? also marginRight work for Button in UiBinder, how can u explain?

Comment: 1. As I said, you can apply both styles. Just add `!important` to your margin setting. 2. uiBinder works the same way. You probably used `styleName` in UiBinder. If you use `addStyleNames`, you will get the same result as in your code.

Comment: it working here, but if we add "!important" for marginRight, then will it affect other style? or better create new marginRight2 for sake of safety?

Comment: so is it necessary to create "marginRight2 " instead of using "marginRight"?

Comment: No, it will not affect the other styles. `!important` applies to one rule only.